# Where is the type Log defined inside of the Substrate runtime crate?

Tags: rust, substrate

Take a look at [this implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/79dd9c83027495107509b700057d04577a2ea242/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L124-L131):

```
impl consensus::Trait for Runtime {
    type Log = Log;
    type SessionKey = AuthorityId;

    // The Aura module handles offline-reports internally
    // rather than using an explicit report system.
    type InherentOfflineReport = ();
}
```

How is `Log` defined? There is no `use` clause for importing this symbol.

Running

```
cargo rustc -- -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded
```

does not show any `Log` entry with `type` clause. It does show other macro declarations after expanding macros at level 0, but I am not sure if this relevant.

I tried using the Atom IDE because it automatically parses the files and lets you find the definition of the symbols, but it did not help.

How can I find how `Log` is defined?

Comment: @turbulencetoo ,nope, I already checked on it: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html , there is no `Log` there

Comment: well that's `std::prelude`, which is not `rstd:prelude`... I cant find a log in either one though

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/core/sr-std/src/lib.rs

Comment: @turbulencetoo , do you know how to `--pretty` expand to all levels ? not just first level? maybe thats the problem

Comment: It appears to be defined by `construct_runtime!` - if you go to the macro declaration, the output has `enum Log` in it. I don't know how to get the compiler to expand the code out to that point, however.

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel , it is actually seen when doing `cargo expand` , I don't know how did I miss it the first time, it is defined as `pub struct Log(InternalLog);`

Comment: @Nulik maybe you want to answer your own question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Log` is defined by `construct_runtime` macro.
Here are some relevant code:

`construct_runtime` macro:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/950e90e75dc7d16dcf99972fcc733945a832dc3e/srml/support/src/runtime.rs#L79

```
macro_rules! construct_runtime {
    (
        pub enum $runtime:ident with Log ($log_internal:ident: DigestItem<$( $log_genarg:ty ),+>)
            where
                Block = $block:ident,
                NodeBlock = $node_block:ty,
                UncheckedExtrinsic = $uncheckedextrinsic:ident
        {
            $( $rest:tt )*
        }
    )
```

calling `__decl_outer_log`

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/950e90e75dc7d16dcf99972fcc733945a832dc3e/srml/support/src/runtime.rs#L267

```
    $crate::__decl_outer_log!(
        $runtime;
        $log_internal < $( $log_genarg ),* >;
        {};
        $(
            $name: $module:: $( < $module_instance >:: )? { $( $modules $( ( $( $modules_args )* ) )* )* }
        )*
    );
```

`__decl_outer_log` macro

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/950e90e75dc7d16dcf99972fcc733945a832dc3e/srml/support/src/runtime.rs#L706

```
macro_rules! __decl_outer_log {
    (
        $runtime:ident;
        $log_internal:ident <$( $log_genarg:ty ),+>;
        { $( $parsed:tt )* };
        $name:ident: $module:ident:: $(<$module_instance:ident>::)? {
            Log ( $( $args:ident )* ) $( $modules:ident $( ( $( $modules_args:ident )* ) )* )*
        }
        $( $rest:tt )*
    ) => {
```

calling `impl_outer_log`

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/950e90e75dc7d16dcf99972fcc733945a832dc3e/srml/support/src/runtime.rs#L763

```
(
    $runtime:ident;
    $log_internal:ident <$( $log_genarg:ty ),+>;
    { $(
        $parsed_modules:ident $(< $parsed_instance:ident >)? ( $( $parsed_args:ident )* )
    )* };
) => {
    $crate::paste::item! {
        $crate::runtime_primitives::impl_outer_log!(
            pub enum Log($log_internal: DigestItem<$( $log_genarg ),*>) for $runtime {
                $( [< $parsed_modules $(_ $parsed_instance)? >] $(< $parsed_modules::$parsed_instance >)? ( $( $parsed_args ),* ) ),*
            }
        );
    }
};
```

`impl_outer_log` macro:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/950e90e75dc7d16dcf99972fcc733945a832dc3e/core/sr-primitives/src/lib.rs#L630

```
macro_rules! impl_outer_log {
    (
        $(#[$attr:meta])*
        pub enum $name:ident ($internal:ident: DigestItem<$( $genarg:ty ),*>) for $trait:ident {
            $( $module:ident $(<$instance:path>)? ( $( $sitem:ident ),* ) ),*
        }
    )
```

which actually declare and implement the `Log` struct

You should be able to see the result when `cargo expand` the runtime crate.